# Running a crontab job for 12 months

Tags: linux, cron

I am trying to write a crontab job that will run for 12 months and stop running after that period of time. Kind of like a license that renews every year. Is this possible?
My thought process is using the `date` command within the `crontab -e` file.
Any ideas on this will be greatly appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepare license-check script. Its task is to verify your monthly script is valid. If monthly script not valid disable monthly script.

1. Put your monthly script in /etc/cron.monthly

2.1  Use `at` command to run 'license-check' on your monthly script at specific time. Once.

or

2.2  Use `crontab` to run 'license-check' once a year.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a shell script that is called from the crontab. There you can check if "today" is before a given date you run the crontab eg every day:

```
futuredate=$(date -d 2021-08-19 +%s)
today=$(date +%s)

if [ $futuredate -ge $today ];
then
  echo "put yout command here"
fi
```

You can then run the crontab as usual. And if the date is over your command in the if-statement won't be called

(EDIT) more meaningful variable names